# Como coletar Tweets em tempo real com tweepy no Python

Tags: python, twitter-api

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que consiste em coletar os tweets postados aqui no Brasil, estou usando a API do Twitter e a biblioteca tweepy do Python, eu consigo pegar os termos que estão no trending topics e fazer uma busca por eles e coletar seus tweets, porém eu queria fazer isso de forma aleatória e em tempo real. Eu consigo fazer coletas em tempo real com o `StreamListener` mas não sei como faço para coletar os tweets de forma aleatória.
meu código:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)


myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = autenticacao, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=['python'])
```

no `myStream.filter` eu especifico o que eu quero buscar, mas eu não quero fazer uma busca específica eu quero coletar os tweets que estão sendo postados aqui no Brasil em tempo real. se alguém souber alguma maneira de fazer isso me ajudaria bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importando o tweepy:

```
import tweepy
```

Sobrescreve tweepy.StreamListener:

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
```

Credenciais:

```
consumer_key = 'SUA_API_KEY'
consumer_secret = 'SUA_API_SECRET'

access_token = 'SEU_ACCESS_TOKEN'
access_token_secret = 'SEU_ACCESS_SECRET_TOKEN'
```

Criando a autenticação:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
```

Instanciando MyStreamListener:

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = auth, listener = myStreamListener)
```

Aqui você filtra os tweets pela localização:

```
location = [-73.5,-33.0,-34.7,4.9]
myStream.filter( locations= location)
```

*Obs: Você deve melhorar a longitude e latitude para pegar exatamente do Brasil. Coloquei somente um exemplo.*

Você pode utilizar [este](https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/) site para pegar os dados de localização.

Comment: Vlw amigo, me salvou aqui!

Comment: Você tem que desenhar em torno do mapa do Brasil que embaixo ele gera umas coordenadas.

Comment: estou  conseguindo

Comment: Você sabe se e possível passar duas localizações?

Comment: Possivelmente sim, em forma de duas listas diferentes, exemplo: `location = [[-73.5,-33.0,-34.7,4.9], [-76.5,-32.0,-32.7,2.9]]`

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: Por nada Renato! Abraço!